# How to set a value of one class property to another class property in another generic list in C#?

Tags: c#, class, object, generic-list

I have two `List<T>`: `List<Address>` and `List<AddressType>`. These are the properties of both classes:

Address

```
 public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    }
```

AddressType

```
 public class AddressType
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string AddressTypeName { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to set the value of each Id of Address item in the `List<Address>` to AddressId of each AddressType in the `List<AddressType>` according to their order in the list. if I have multiple Addresses and AddressTypes which I store on `List<Address>` and `List<AddressType>` respectively, what is the best way to set the values?

Comment: Clearly formulated. Did absolutely not deserve the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enumerators, given that the counts of two list are same.

```
var addressEnumerator = addressList.GetEnumerator();
var typeEnumerator = typeList.GetEnumerator();

while (addressEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    typeEnumerator.MoveNext();
    addressEnumerator.Current.Id = typeEnumerator.Current.AddressId;
    // throws exception when typeList is shorter than addressList
}
```

This would be more efficient than looping or indexing the two list seperately.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < addressList.Count; i++)
        {
            addressList[i].Id = typeList[i].AddressId;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < adressList.Count; i++)
 {
 adressList[i].Id = typeList[i].AddressId;
 }
```

If necessary, you can also add a check if both lists have the same length:

```
if(addressList.Count != typeList.Count)
 {
 throw new Exception("the lists do not have the same length");
 }
```